# ClassCastException on Multi-Dimentional Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, classcastexception

I was trying to understand the execution logic behind the following block of code:

```
Integer[][] mdArray = new Integer[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 } };

List<Integer[]> mdArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

// Iterate through every row of mdArray
for (Integer[] obj : mdArray) {
    mdArrayList.add(obj);
}

/* Throws ClassCastException because it cannot resolve the final array size?
 * 
 * i.e. it is a proper RTError.
 * 
 */
Integer[][] toArray = (Integer[][]) (mdArrayList.toArray());
```

The above code compiles fine but throws a ClassCastException at runtime when executing the final line. My understanding is that JVM cannot execute this code in runtime because even though toArray() chucks out an array of elements in mdArrayList, the destination type cannot be resolved or promoted to a valid one?

Any explanation will be appreciated! I am simply trying to understand if this sort of code execution must be avoided or exception-handled to outut something more appropriate to user needs.

Comment: `List.toArray` returns an `Object[]`. How would it do anything else?

Comment: @BoristheSpider      yes I know it does. My question was how does it decide how to resolve this into a MD array. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: There is no such thing as an MD array in Java.

Comment: @BoristheSpider    MD Array is multi-dimensional array. You can do myArray[][] in java, which is 2-D (hence, multidimensional). Anyway, I got my explaination....thanks

Comment: Nope, it's an array of `int[]`. It's "jagged". It's not an MD array.

Comment: Thanks all for the import nudges about Arrays and Collections. I accepted Elliot's answer because of the usage of deepToString() method (I've never had to look at this before!!!). cheers @ElliotFrisch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be casting. Pass an `Integer[][]` to `toArray`. Something like

```
Integer[][] toArray = mdArrayList.toArray(new Integer[][] {});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(toArray));
```

Output is

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Or `Integer[][]::new`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The above also works in Java7, but in April... :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch       nice solution - simple +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Integer[][] toArray = mdArrayList.toArray(new Integer[mdArrayList.size()][]);
```

If you don't provide an argument to the `toArray` method, the return type will always be `Object[]` regardless of the actual type of what is inside the list.

If you do provide an argument, you can either choose to make it a zero-length array (`new Integer[0][]`), in which case the `toArray` method will create a new array of the same type; or you can provide an array if the correct size, and then the `toArray` method will use that array. The latter is slightly more efficient than the former, but not something that you need to worry much about.

Comment: nice. Thanks for the explaination more than what to fix. I just had a second read through API docs about toArray(Object[] obj) and it said that it will return default Object[] if a type and size isn't specified - just when I thought I read everything.